# How to retrieve single records that occurs more than once in db using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6

In my project, I need to get the `cashcalls` on a particular date. The db contains list of `cashcalls` of the day. I had provided a `datepicker` to select the date.

Based on the selected date, I want to get the distinct `cashcall` names. But I am getting the names repeatedly.

How can I get the unique names from db using Entity Framework?

### Example

> I have cashCall1, cashCall1, cashcall1, cashcall2, cashcall2 for the
>   date December9th.
>
> I need output as cashCall1, cashCall2.

Thanks

### My code is as below

```
List<string> cashcallName = new List<string>();
string cash = null;
try
{
    var cashcalls = context.CashCalls.Where(d => d.Date == _date).Select(n=>n.CashCallName).Distinct().ToList();
    foreach (var data in cashcalls)
    {
        cash = data;
        cashcallName.Add(cash);
    }
    string CashCallsbyDate = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cashcallName);
    return CashCallsbyDate;
}
```

Comment: is one of the cashcalls suppose to have a capital C and the other a lower case? You have  cashCall1, cashcall1,

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't add .Distinct() after the Select(***)?

Comment: @HedrickW No. All the names look like cashCall1, cashCall1, cashCall1, cashCall2, cashCall2.

Comment: hmm i guess you just have to groupby CashCallName for achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this : you will get `Distinct` data --

```
var cashcalls = context.CashCalls.Where(d => d.Date == _date)
                       .GroupBy(g =>   g.CashCallName)
                       .Select(n => n.First().CashCallName)
                       .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. Instead of First(), it was asking to use FirstOrDefault(). Achieved.

Comment: it was according to situation.